# Fetch and Update large population of Entity records in Console app

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Looking for the best approach to fetch and update the entities in bulk. Please suggest best approach to deal with this requirement, I am fetching List of Guids (~80K+) from an external database and want to update an entity in CRM by increment the counter integer field and setting one option set field. So far as per my understanding following are the possible approaches :

1. Using Early-bound classes - Querying the context in batches by passing 5K entity id at once and then looping through the entitylist and update the entity context with-in foreach loop.
2. Using QueryExpression - Passing the Guid ids in batch/page of 5k in query expression using ConditionOperator.In operator, retriveMultipleRespone and then loop through the entities and preparing the updaterequest collection and call executeMultiple again repeat the same for remaining pages.

Please suggest which approach will better or any-other approach to handling it more efficient way. Can we use multi-threading here ?

Answer (score 0):

Early bound classes simply provide strong typing for CRM objects and Early vs Late Bound has little or no effect on performance. In both cases you would want to use a RetrieveMultiple operation to get the records, and an ExecuteMultiple operation to update them. Since you already have the Guids, you may not need to retrieve the records before you update them, this would obviously improve performance.

From the Microsoft documentation on ExecuteMultiple the operation has the following pertinent limitations:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/use-executemultiple-improve-performance-bulk-data-load
- There is a limit of 2 concurrent ExecuteMultiple requests per organization
- The default max batch size for ExecuteMultiple is 1k records
Both of these settings can be changed on the org level

You can use multi-threading, and it might improve performance, but I don't have much experience in this area. For only 80k records you probably don't need to bother.

Comment: Thanks Zach for your response, Though I have Guid list but still I'll have to fetch the retriveMultiple because I need to increment counter field for which I need to retrive it and then update the entity record. My question is - In earlybound there is messages like  context.Attach(entityObj); context.UpdateObject(entityObj); context.SaveChanges(entityObj) will perform better if I save context in the batch within foreach loop or Using ExecuteMultiple ?

Comment: ExecuteMultiple is designed for this sort of integration and will perform better.